# AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties() seems not to work for xml configured contexts

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to manually inject a beans autowired dependency by using AutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(). But it only seems to work if the bean which should be injected was configured in a Java class. If it is configured in a XML context file it does not work.

**Test cases:**

```
public class InjectorTest {

@Test
public void testAnnotationInjector() {
    AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = null;
    try {
        TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
        context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SomeServiceConfig.class);;
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(testBean, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, false);

        assertTrue(testBean.getSomeService() != null);
    } finally {
        if (context != null) {
            context.close();
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void testXmlInjector() {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = null;
    try {
        TestBean testBean = new TestBean();
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-some-service-context.xml");
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(testBean, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, false);

        assertTrue(testBean.getSomeService() != null);
    } finally {
        if (context != null) {
            context.close();
        }
    }
}

private class TestBean {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService someService;

    public SomeService getSomeService() {
        return someService;
    }
}
```

The first test case runs successfully. The second one however fails. Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Here is the rest of the code:

**SomeService.java**

```
public class SomeService {

 public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("Did something");
 }
}
```

**JAVA context configuration**

```
@Configuration
public class SomeServiceConfig {

  @Bean
  public SomeService someService() {
      return new SomeService();
  }
}
```

**test-some-service-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<bean class="webapplication.injector.SomeService"></bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second test case fails because `TestBean` don't have a setter for someService property and context don't register an `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`

So, to fix it you could add a setter for someService or add a  `<context:annotation-config/>`  to bean definition file.

Comment: Why does the first one pass?

Comment: The first one passes because the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` assumes annotation based configuration and as such the `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` is registered by default (basically everything that the `<context:annotation-config />` does is default for the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`.